# Gradle + OSGi Liferay7 module, include transitive dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, liferay, osgi, liferay-7

I've built a sample module with the following structure and dependencies:

```
osgi-lfr-module
+--- module0
|     \--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5
+--- module1
|     \--- module0
\--- module2
      +--- module1
      \--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1
```

I want to build a single `jar` to deploy in Liferay 7 containing modules 0, 1 and 2 and 3rd party dependencies. I know it's not the recommended approach, but I'm would like to know how to achieve it.

`module2/build.gradle` file is:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.liferay:com.liferay.gradle.plugins:2.0.10'
    }   
}

apply plugin: "com.liferay.plugin"

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

dependencies {
    compile project(':module1')

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
}
```

I've followed the steps from [OSGi Module Dependencies](https://web.liferay.com/es/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/osgi-module-dependencies). Up until now, I'm able to add direct dependencies in `module2/bnd.bnd`:

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Export-Package: com.test.module2, com.test.module1, com.test.module0
Bundle-ClassPath: \
    .,\
    lib/module1.jar,\
    lib/commons-collections4.jar
-includeresource: \
    lib/module1.jar=module1-1.0.0.jar,\
    lib/commons-collections4.jar=commons-collections4-4.1.jar
```

But if I try to add transitive deps, like `module0`:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: \
    .,\
    lib/module0.jar,\
    lib/module1.jar,\
    lib/commons-collections4.jar
-includeresource: \
    lib/module0.jar=module0-1.0.0.jar,\
    lib/module1.jar=module1-1.0.0.jar,\
    lib/commons-collections4.jar=commons-collections4-4.1.jar
```

Build fails with the following error:

```
:module2:jar
[Input file does not exist: module0-1.0.0.jar]
[No sub JAR or directory lib/module0.jar]
```

Can anyone help me to find out what I'm doing wrong? And, is there any way less manual to add transitive dependencies?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There's a typo in the second `bnd.bnd` snippet you added: I think it should be `lib/module0.jar=module0-1.0.0.jar`, not `lib/module1.jar=module0-1.0.0.jar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com.liferay.plugin` applies [`gradle-bundle-plugin`](https://github.com/TomDmitriev/gradle-bundle-plugin/) to invoke Bnd and create the JAR, so you can use all its options. [This](https://github.com/TomDmitriev/gradle-bundle-plugin/#passing-transitive-dependencies-to-bnd) is the one you need, please add it to your *module2*'s `build.gradle`:

```
bundle {
    includeTransitiveDependencies = true
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks.

Comment: Anyone knows the maven equivalent of this?